# One Component with multiple theme styles (Material-UI v5)

Tags: material-ui

Wondering if it's possible to do the following scenario. I'd like to create a new component that is actually a copy of an existing one with another style (Theme based).

Let's take for example the Button , with a new pseudo component *MyButton*

```
MyButton -> is a Button
```

In the Theme I'd like to be able to have

```
Theme {
    components: {
        MuiButton :  ....  // styles for <Button/>
        MyButton :  ....  // styles for <MyButton/> 
    }
}
```

So from a styling point of view I have two different components (it's not variants as both components might have their own list of variants).

As an amazing bonus, how would you do if MyButton is part of a new component that uses the Button class for creating a more complex component.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it's not possible to reset styles for the core components, but that would be possible after we release the `@material-ui/unstyled` package. The core components would be basically `styled()` version of the unstyled components. That being said, developers can use the `styled()` utility on top of the unstyled components where they can define different theme names, resulting in different standalone components.